No termina el proceso de crear un proyecto en angular
hola gente necesito su ayuda urgente, estoy empezando la clase de aplicacion web y estamos en el tema de angular y no se termina de cargar el proyecto, ya actualice el node.js y el npm y aun asi sigue sin terminar de cargar. ¿Podrian decirme que puedo hacer?, Por favor 

Has probado usar CSS en lugar de SASS?

bueno en clases estamos usando el Sass, pero si tambien intente con el CSS y lo mismo solo se queda en eso y nada mas

Cuanto tiempo tarda? en que carpeta lo estás creando?

Puede ser un problema de red y del disco duro. npm para angular, al crear el proyecto descarga e instala muchos paquetes. Si tu disco duro es un poco viejo (HDD) y tu velocidad de internet ronda los 10Mb entonces va a tardar de entre 20 a 40 minutos. El problema principal radica en que las librerias son ligeras, pero son muchas, y archivos pequeños, lo que limita la velocidad de descarga continua y aumenta el resago en la escriuta.

entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda, he estado sufriendo con esto que luego de casi hora y media se pudo cargar

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
